# Mbstring installed, still getting "Call to undefined function mb_strtolower()"

Tags: magento-2.1, php

My configuration details

PHP 7

Magento version 2.1

Also installed Mbstring extension,

but still getting error

```
Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower()
```

After throwing reindex command,

```
magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: after installing mbstring. have you restart apache?

Comment: yes chirag. I have restarted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using php-fpm you should restart it too, because the new extension is installed but not loaded yet. See [similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858598/how-to-install-php-extensions-on-nginx). You can detect is extension loaded using the `phpinfo();`: if the extension was successfully loaded you can see something like this:

[image: mbstring extension in phpinfo]

To restart php-fpm on ubuntu use the command like:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

You can find more info by googling *"How to restart php-fpm %your distr%"*.

Comment: @MagentoDeveloper I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: i already installed mbstring but still getting error why??

Comment: @prabhakaran7 please, check php version which your web-server using. It is possible that you have many php instances on your server.

Comment: shared hosting amd php 7.0

Answer (score 0):

For command line, You have setup a php variable.By which you are running php and magento commands on Command line interface.
A php.ini is associated with that particular php variable's php configurations. Please check in that file if php_mbstring.dll is enabled or not.
Clear chache and remove generation folder in magento-root/var folder.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\p4p\vendor\magento\framework\Event\Manager.php on line 56

Getting this error while running my project on localhost.